# SSRS Hide columns based on Multi valued parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, multivalue

I have an SSRS report that has two parameters. A Description and Partner name. You can select more than one description or all of them but only one partner. When i select one or more descriptions report must only show columns that have values.
Issue is when i select all of them the report defaults to the structure of the first description regardless of the fact that when the 2nd or 3rd description row starts there is data in that column and it should be showing it. So it ends up hiding columns that should be showing

I have the below code in code visibility expression
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Working_Office.Value),True,False)

I suspect my issue has to do with the Multi valued parameter,

HELP

Comment: Showing the structure of your table would be helpful. Also, you may want to wrap a `Max` function around the `Fields!Working_Office.Value` column so that it's not arbitrarily checking one value.

Comment: StevenWhite is there a way to send this to you via email?

Comment: In order for the answer to be helpful for the rest of the community it would be best to edit your question to include as much detail as possible so that we can document the issue along with the answer here.